# how to install cmake latest version in ubuntu with out net connection

Tags: cmake, cryptography, ubuntu-14.04, cmake-gui

I want to install cmake in Ubuntu 14.04 in offline.
Could you please tell me.How to download from internet (provide link) and install cmake in Ubuntu 14.04. 
I need cmake for run cyptominisat programmes

Answer (score 1):

Download CMake from the official site

1. Visit https://cmake.org/download/
2. Find and download cmake-3.7.1-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz (or newer)
3. Transfer this file to the offline system

From the offline system:

1. Run `sudo tar -xzC /opt` for the installation bundle
2. This will install cmake to /opt/cmake-3.7.1
3. Add `/opt/cmake-3.7.1/bin` to your PATH